# Shortcut to close a opened tab in android studio

Tags: android-studio

**What is the shortcut to close the opened tab in android studio?**

I'm new to the android studio. I tried with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. It's not working. I searched for a while. But I haven't get it. Any one please provide me the shortcut to close the opened tab.

Comment: This works on Mac also, since some of the new macs don't have F keys.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> in order to close opened tabs in Android Studio

Comment: Got it. Thanks Flash. Is there any possibility to change the shortcut to Ctrl+W.

Comment: Yeah, clic **CTRL+ALT+S** to open Settings, search on the top left bar for *Keymap*. Then, on right side of the window, clic on the search bar and search *Close*. You will find it under *Editor Tabs* category, checking the shortcut on the right (**CTRL+F4**)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, as soon as I pressed CTRL+F4 not only shortcut functionality disabled even I can't type anything in editor :( http://stackoverflow.com/q/37080941/513413

Comment: And, what is obvious, CMD + F4 on Mac

Comment: Flash your solution works great, just remember when you search in there you should choose "close" and not Active tab or any other.

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned above, type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>  to get into settings and in the keymap dialog search for `Close`, but the thing you want to reassign is

`Close Active Editor`

Comment: Thank you for "Close Active Editor".... I was assigning to "Close Active Tab" and it wasn't working :)   Now it does

Answer (score 15):

For Mac it is not set by default. Here is how I did it.
`Android Studio 4.1 > Preferences > Keymap` search for `Close Active Editor` right click > `Add Keyboard Shortcut`. Then assign anything you want. Alt+W is a good one.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was working just fine for the past decade but after upgrading to Arctive Fox last week it just stopped working. Not sure if the keymap got reset or the default changed. But this worked great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

If you right click on a tab header, the context menu shows you the current key binding next to the word **Close** (by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps mentioned in other comments (type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to get into settings and in the keymap dialog search for Close) and what you actually need to change is [editor tabs] / [close]

(android studio 3.6.1)

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, it's `command` + `F4`.

If you're like me, you may have to do `command` + `fn` + `F4`