# Assigned shortcut to Android Studio doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I wanted to close active tab by shortcut in Android studio. I found <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> does the job from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31159594/513413). Although it closed active tab, keyboard functionality disabled in a way that I couldn't type anything in editor (modify my classes).

So, I decided to change its shortcut. I assigned <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to `close active tab` and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to `reopen closed tab` as you see in following screenshot. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> does its job properly while when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> nothing happens (active tab doesn't close).

My OS is Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Hm, Ctrl+Shift+W is already assigned to "Shrink Selection" in my version of Android Studio, and Ctrl + W is set to Expand Selection. Did you change the defaults?

Comment: BTW, don't know about Ubuntu, but in m version of Gentoo (though running KDE, not GNOME), Ctrl + F4 is set to "Switch to Desktop 4". Not having alternate desktops set up might have been why you lost keyboard.

Comment: @CaptJak thanks, regard your first comment, yes, I asked Keymap to unassign it from previous value, Shrink Selection. CTRL+W was working fine for "Shrink Selection" before I change it. However new assignment does not work :( In my Ubuntu Environment CTRL+F4 doesn't do anything, bytheway.

Comment: I would try restarting Android Studio after changing something like that, if it doesn't work, that is.

Comment: I just restarted, no luck :(

Comment: I would check the "Global Keyboard Shortcuts" on Ubuntu, and just make sure it isn't bound to anything, even if it doesn't do anything when you press it.

Comment: Just for kicks, in the "Keymaps" dropdown, select "Default for XWin" and not "Default for XWin copy". If "Close Active Tab" is not set to Ctrl + W, set it there.

Comment: thanks for help, "Default for XWin copy" created as my change is based on "Default for XWin" if I modify it again it created another "Default for XWin copy 0". I even checked  "Global Keyboard Shortcuts" and there is nothing tied to CTRL+W :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111258/discussion-between-captjak-and-hesam).

Answer (score 3):

Close Active Tab closes the active tool window. You need to find "Close" under "Main menu" -> "Window" -> "Editor Tabs". Change this to "Ctrl + W" and it should work.